# React Beautiful DND draggable card position problem while drag

Tags: reactjs, npm, react-hooks, drag-and-drop, react-beautiful-dnd

I facing a gap issue between the card and cursor. The cursor is not stick while dragging a card.
Here I am attaching a screenshot that shows gap and also insert code.

[image]

This is a column and it contains a scrollbar and the gap increase when scroll then dragging.

Here is the Draggable component code

```
 <Draggable key={`${id}`} isDragDisabled={idDisabled} draggableId={JSON.stringify(actionData)} index={index} >
            {(provided, snapshot) => (
                <div
                    className={`rx-actions-card-list draggable-card ${moment(dueDate) > moment() ? 'border-left-green' : 'border-left-red'}`}
                    ref={provided.innerRef}
                    {...provided.draggableProps}
                    {...provided.dragHandleProps}
                    style={{
                        ...provided.draggableProps.style,
                    }}
                >
```